# Can the sum of two pregaussian random variables be zero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-theory, random-variables

Do there exist any two Sub-Gaussian random variables with variance 1 such that the sum of them is the $0$ random variable, whose value is $0$ with probability $1$?

Comment: Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Certainly; let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = -X$.

If you want them to be independent then this is not possible.  If $X,Y$ each have variance 1 and are independent, then $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) +\operatorname{Var}(Y) = 2 \ne \operatorname{Var}(0)$.

Indeed, the only way for the sum of two independent random variables to be 0 is if they are both constants. To be precise:

> If $X,Y$ are any two independent random variables (not necessarily sub-Gaussian), and $X+Y = 0$ almost surely, then there is a constant $c$ such that $X=c$ and $Y=-c$ almost surely.

*Proof.*  If $X+Y = 0$ then $Y = -X$, so $X$ is independent of $-X$, and it follows that $X$ is independent of $X$.  In particular, for any $t$, the event $\{X > t\}$ is independent of itself, and so must have probability 0 or 1.  By taking $c = \sup\{t : P(X>t) = 1\}$, we can see that $P(X=c) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you mean that the Sub-Gaussian random variables will be both $0$ if independent? and why is that? Thanks!

Comment: @bolia: I added some more details.  Sub-Gaussian doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Comment: Dear Nate, Thank you for your answer, but Why must the event {X>t} is independent of itself have probability 0 or 1? as X and Y independent means $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. Thanks!

Comment: @bolia: That isn't really a very good definition for our purposes, since if the random variable is constant it won't have a density.  But you could integrate that definition to find the same property of the cdf's: $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x) F_Y(y)$.  If $F$ is independent of itself then $F_X(x) = F_{X,X}(x,x) = F_X(x)^2$, so $F_X(x)$ must be 0 or 1.  In particular, $P(X>t)$ is $1-F_X(t)$, so it must also be 0 or 1.  This fact follows more directly if you are doing probability from the point of view of measure theory.